# Implementing pagination in Angular 8 paginator is unresponsive

Tags: typescript, angular-material, pagination, angular8, angular-material-table

We have a simple mat-table and we want to add pagination to it.

app.ts

```
import {Component, OnInit, ViewChild, AfterViewInit} from '@angular/core';
import {MatTableDataSource} from "@angular/material/table";
import {MatPaginator} from "@angular/material/paginator";

export class App implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  dataSource: MatTableDataSource<any>;
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator, {static: true}) paginator: MatPaginator;

  displayedColumns: string[] = ['name', 'age', 'city'];
  tableData = [
    {name: 'John', age: 30, city: 'NYC'},
    {name: 'David', age: 25, city: 'BRKLYN'},
    {name: 'Mike', age: 35, city: 'NYC'},
    {name: 'Jane', age: 25, city: 'BRKLYN'},
    {name: 'Jeniffer', age: 22, city: 'NJ'},
    {name: 'Sarah', age: 31, city: 'LNDN'},
  ];

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.tableData);
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
    console.log('data: ', this.dataSource.data)
  }
```

app.html

```
              <mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource">
                        <ng-container [matColumnDef]="col" *ngFor="let col of displayedColumns; let i = index">
                          <th class="description-cell-head"
                              *matHeaderCellDef > {{col}}</th>
                          <td class="description-cell"
                              mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{ element[col] }} </td>
                        </ng-container>

                      <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>

                      <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns"></mat-row>

                  </mat-table>
                  <mat-paginator [length]="tableData.length" [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 25, 30,100]"></mat-paginator>
```

app.css

```
.description-cell {
  padding-right: 16px !important;
  text-align: right;
}
.description-cell-head {
  padding-right: 16px !important;
  text-align: right;
  font-size: larger;
}
.mat-header-cell{
  padding-right: 16px !important;
    text-align: right !important;
}
.mat-cell {
  padding-left: 8px;
  padding-right: 8px;
}
```

1. Upon inspect pagination seems to be undefined
2. In the UI itself - toggling the pageSizeOptions does not change the  number of elements per page.

We have tried setting pagination manually in the TS with

```
export class App implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild('stepper', {static: false}) stepper: MatStepper;
  dataSource: MatTableDataSource<any>;
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator, {static: true}) paginator: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild(MatSort, {static: false}) sort: MatSort;

  set matPaginator(mp: MatPaginator) {
    this.paginator = mp;
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
  }
```